# Heapify not function while adding new element

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, insert, heap

I want to insert some nodes, it seems the function is buggy. It is able to insert but not able to perform heapify. I'm wondering the index is messed up after adding a new element. Any comments are welcoming. Thanks.

```
def heapify(arr, n, i): 
    smallest = i  
    l = 2 * i + 1  
    r = 2 * i + 2  

    if l < n and arr[l] < arr[smallest]:  
        smallest = l  

    if r < n and arr[r] < arr[smallest]:  
        smallest = r  

    if smallest != i:  
        (arr[i],  
         arr[smallest]) = (arr[smallest], 
                           arr[i]) 

        heapify(arr, n, smallest) 

def insertNode(arr, n, key):
    n=n+1
    arr.append(key)
    heapify(arr, n, n-1)

def printArray(arr, n):    
    for i in range(n):
        print(arr[i])


alist = [8, 9, 15, 16, 11, 17]
n = len(alist)
insertNode(alist, n, 12)
insertNode(alist, n, 18)
insertNode(alist, n, 6)
printArray(alist, n+3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering `alist` is already **heapified**, you are incorrectly implementing the **`heapify`** method, when you insert a node in heap you have to take *bottom up approach*, I've made few corrections to your code, have a look at it,

```
def heapify(arr, n, i):
    parent = (i - 1) // 2

    if parent >= 0 and  arr[i] < arr[parent]:
        arr[i], arr[parent] = arr[parent], arr[i]

        heapify(arr, n, parent)

def insertNode(arr, key):
    arr.append(key)
    n = len(arr)
    heapify(arr, n, n-1)


def printArray(arr, n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(arr[i])


alist = [8, 9, 15, 16, 11, 17]
n = len(alist)

insertNode(alist, 12)
insertNode(alist, 18)
insertNode(alist, 6)
n += 3  # ---> increment size of array after inserting element

printArray(alist, n)
```

The **output** will be,

```
6
8
12
9
11
17
15
18
16
```

Hope it helps.